# android get id from ViewGroup

Tags: java, android

I have an ArrayAdapter with a button:

```
 public View getView(final int position, @Nullable final View convertView, @NonNull final ViewGroup parent)

 btnClickMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
```

and this is what  `view.getParent().getParent()` gives

```
android.widget.ListView{7d85545 VFED.VC.. .F....ID 16,70-704,1008 #7f0800cc app:id/tray_tab1}
```

How can i get `app:id/tray_tab1` or `tray_tab1`?

Comment: Try (View) view.getParentForAccessibility().getParent().getId()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

```
  int parentId = ((View) view.getParent().getParent()).getId();
```

And now you can compare id with `R.id` like

```
 if (parentId == R.id.tray_tab1) {
       // Do what ever you want
 }
```